# Xlsx file modified in Python (Pandas/Openpyxl) has not same properties as the same xlsx file modified in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have an xlsx file which I modify in python (using Pandas) based on several conditions. The output xlsx file then I put into data quality tracking software. The modified file is however rejected, because the file is not recognized. When I open the modified xlsx file in Excel, press ctrl+s and then upload the file, everything works fine.

The modified xlsx file as output from python has size 400 kB, when I open it in Excel, save it and close it, it has size 600 kB. Nevertheless both Excel files are from user point of view **exactly** the same.

I suspect that Python writes Excel in little bit different way then does excel itself and therefore its not recognizeable by data quality tracking software.

Is there any way to get xlsx file from Python with same properties as Excel itself? Adding 2 lines at the end of the code just to open modified xlsx and save the file with for example Openpyxl returns again 400 kB file, instead of 600 kB.

Comment: There's probably a bug with the data quality tracking software. openpyxl, which Pandas uses by default, produces extremely high quality XLSX files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue before, defining an engine did the job. Let me know if it helped for you:

```
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Comment: My output workbook has many worksheets, so I had to use ExcelWriter with defined engine openpyxl. That being said, your answer actualy solved the issue, with xlsxwriter as engine, the output workbook lost all it's original formatting and colors of the cells, but that does not matter, as this workbook is used only by the Data Quality Check software and it accepts it. Thank you alot!