# Python excel formula file saving issues with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm running into a weird issue when saving changes to an .xlsx file. For testing purposes, the file I'm trying to modify has 10 lines with the last one being formulas. I'm trying to add two names only to the first column and then append that to the file. What's happening is that the once the code is executed the appended file is half the size of the original (adding the two names manually) and when comparing it to the original using Spreadsheet Compare it shows that the new appended file is missing all the formulas in the last row. What's weird though is if I open this new file, it actually has all the formulas and functions identical to the original. The only way to actually have this file updated is if I open and manually save the appended file in excel and then file size gets updated accordingly.

Not sure why this is happening, here the code

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.formats.excel

pandas.io.formats.excel.ExcelFormatter.header_style = None

file = r'C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\Test\Project\AutoTracker\tracker.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(file,skipfooter=1)

firstNames = {'ABC': "John", 'DEF': "Tom"}

df[1] = df['Name'].map(firstNames)

with pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
    df[1].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, startrow=1,startcol=1, header=None)
```

I created a copy of the original and made the same changes of adding the two names to compare it to the Python generated version and here are the results:

[image]

Note the file size differences in the new file being 6KB while the original with the manually added changes are 11KB.

This is what the excel file actually looks like with the two names added to it:
[image]

The excel file looks the same for both versions just for some reason it's not being saved correctly when generated in Python.

Comment: Found similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737128/xlsx-file-modified-in-python-pandas-openpyxl-has-not-same-properties-as-the-sa, seems changing the engine to 'xlsxwriter' can possibly fix this however it removes formatting since it does not support appending. Still need to find a solution using 'openpyxl'

Comment: Using Openpyxl is different from using Excel to modify a xlsx file. Openpyxl modifies the file using the OOXML interface. To put it simply if the file was originally created and saved using Excel then after saving xlsx file with Openpyxl some of the xml or other files that make up the xlsx file may not be retained thus the file could be smaller than original even though you added data to the file. Opening the Openpyxl saved file in Excel and save again and Excel will re-add these files so file is re-sized to the original. So as far as I see there is no issue.

Comment: I don't know if this is documented to determine what's removed and why, although you can unzip the orig and new xlsx files and compare to see what's different and missing. If necessary raise an issue with Openpyxl devs to find out why. I suspect it might be the OOXML interface.

Comment: Hmm, that would explain the file size differences, my only concern was that when using Spreadsheet Compare it shows that the formulas on row 10 are missing from the openpyxl generated file. Though when manually opening the file and when comparing the zip file with the original it looks to be there so maybe it's a non-issue and the problem was with the comparison software I used.